# epoch in seconds to MJD conversion in C

Tags: c

I wanted to convert the given time in epoch format to MJD (Modified Julian Day). But not getting exact MJD equivalent. I think missing some offset value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <memory.h>


int get_mjd (int Y, int M, int D)
{
    int L = 0, MJD = 0;
    if ((M == 1) || (M == 2))
        L = 1;
    MJD = 14956 + D + (int)((Y - L) * 365.25) +
            (int)((M + 1 + L * 12) * 30.60001);
    return MJD;
}


int main(){
        time_t start;
        int mjd;
        struct tm start_tm;

         start = 1442286867; // Tue, 15 Sep 2015 03:14:27 GMT
         memcpy(&start_tm, localtime(&start),sizeof(struct tm));


         printf("year:%d\tmonth: %d\tday: %d\n",start_tm.tm_year,start_tm.tm_mon,start_tm.tm_mday);

        mjd = get_mjd(start_tm.tm_year,start_tm.tm_mon, start_tm.tm_mday);

        printf("mjd: %d\n",mjd);

return 0;
}
```

Output:
year:115        month: 8        day: 15
mjd: 57249

Expected mjd should is 57280

Please let me know what could be missing here.

Comment: Where are you getting the Gregorian calendar - to - Modified Julian Day formula from? It's very different than the one on Wikipedia (not that the Wikipedia one is correct, of course).

Comment: Not sure about the exact source of this formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was yet another off by one error. struct tm returns month with range 0-11.
I needed to +1 to tm_mon before using get_mjd(). Now it works!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't *need* the date broken down into Gregorian calendar year/month/day values, there's a much simpler way.

```
double mjd(time_t epoch_time)
{
    return epoch_time / 86400.0 + 40587;
}
```

The value 40587 is the number of days between the MJD epoch (1858-11-17) and the Unix epoch (1970-01-01), and 86400 is the number of seconds in a day.

Comment: A nice simple Unix `time_t` to mjd.  Suppose code could use `difftime()` for a portable solution that does not depend on `time_t` being in seconds since 1970.

Answer (score 1):

Ref [Modified Julian Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Variants):  Days since November 17, 1858

`get_mjd()` oddly references `Y` as years from 1900, yet `M` in the traditional 1 = January, 2 = February, etc.

`get_mjd()` works for years in the range 1898 to 2099, but fails outside that.

```
// For years from 1900, limited range
int get_mjd (int Y, int M, int D) {
    int L = 0, MJD = 0;
    if ((M == 1) || (M == 2))
        L = 1;
    MJD = 14956 + D + (int)((Y - L) * 365.25) +
            (int)((M + 1 + L * 12) * 30.60001);
    return MJD;
}
```

---

The following works over a *much* larger range or the Gregorian calendar.
`M,D` not limited to their usual range and does not need floating point math.

```
#define DaysPer400Years   (365L*400 + 97)
#define DaysPer100Years   (365L*100 + 24)
#define DaysPer4Years     (365*4    +  1)
#define DaysPer1Year      365
#define MonthsPerYear     12
#define MonthsPer400Years (12*400)
#define MonthMarch        3
#define mjdOffset         (678881  /* Epoch Nov 17, 1858 */)

static const short DaysMarch1ToBeginingOfMonth[12] = { 
    0, 
    31, 
    31 + 30, 
    31 + 30 + 31, 
    31 + 30 + 31 + 30, 
    31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31, 
    31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31,
    31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30,
    31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31,
    31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30, 
    31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31,
    31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 };

int ymd_to_mjd_x(int year, int month, int day) {
  year += month / MonthsPerYear;
  month %= MonthsPerYear;
  // Adjust for month/year to Mar... Feb
  while (month < MonthMarch) {
    month += MonthsPerYear; // Months per year
    year--;
  }
  int d = (year / 400) * DaysPer400Years;
  int y400 = (int) (year % 400);
  d += (y400 / 100) * DaysPer100Years;
  int y100 = y400 % 100;
  d += (y100 / 4) * DaysPer4Years;
  int y4 = y100 % 4;
  d += y4 * DaysPer1Year;
  d += DaysMarch1ToBeginingOfMonth[month - MonthMarch];
  d += day;
  // November 17, 1858 == MJD 0
  d--;
  d -= mjdOffset;
  return d;
}
```